# Physics and logic combination papers

Tags: reference-request

Are there papers that combine the subjects of logic and physics? I would like to read some texts that use both logic and physics. It could be either an application of logic to physics or physics to logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One such paper (an application of Logic to Physics) is *Undecidability of the spectral gap*, by Toby S. Cubbitt, David Perez-Garcia, and Michael M. Wolf, (Nature, **528** (2015), pp. 207–211).